# To modify a python script to search a line in a file for number range

Tags: python-3.x, string, loops, pycharm

I'm trying to write code that will search the files in a directory and for any of them that contain a string of "51" thru "100" on the fifth line, it will print the file name.

I have tried modifying the first statement in the 'for' loop to:

```
s = i
for i in range(51,100):
```

but that just returns an error bc it's looking for a string, not an int

```
path = './data/'
files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "*.crs", recursive=False)]

# Open the file
for f in files:
    line = 5
    fh: TextIO = open(f)
    text = fh.read()

    # Conditions
    for line in f:
        s: str = '62'  # Takes input of a string from user

        if s in text:  # string is present in the text file
            print(f)
        break
    else:
        continue
    fh.close()

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

My current code will print out the name of the file containing '62' on the fifth line. I'm just looking for a way to make it print out all files that contain any number between 51 - 100 on the fifth line.

```
MAT Mathematics
Calculus I
TH 8/26/19 12/11/19
3
62
```

Comment: Please show the first 5 or 6 lines of the contents of a file

Comment: It looks like the end of my post above which I just edited.
But I got it, though, just by changing the lineToCheck to '4'. Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but this is what I came up with. Basically, for each file it opens the file and reads line by line until it gets to the line you want to check. Note that line 5 is the 6th line of the file because line numbers are offsets from 0. Then it checks the line for any numbers in `numbersToCheck`. I've used `str(v) for v in range(51, 100)` on the second line to convert integers into strings, which are then stored in `numbersToCheck`.

```
lineToCheck = 5
numbersToCheck = [str(v) for v in range(51, 100)] #convert integers to strings

path = './data/'
files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "*.crs", recursive=False)]

for f in files:
    fh = open(f) #open the file
    for lineNo, line in enumerate(fh):
        if lineNo == lineToCheck: #Once it gets to the correct line
            if any(numberStr in line for numberStr in numbersToCheck): #Checks for numbers
                print(line)
                break #don'1t continue checking this file, move on to the next.
    fh.close()
```

Comment: 1. Files support context management, use `with` to open/close them. 2. files support the iteration protocol, as you have shown. Then just skip the first lines with one starement only, no enumerate is needed. 3 maybe use a regex to match the strings or double check with the OP what a line in the file contains exactly

Comment: @Pynchia these sound like good edits. I'm not quite sure what you mean by your second point (this is probably a limit of my knowledge). How would you do that? - feel free to edit the answer if you have the rep to do so.

Comment: Investigate `itertools.islice` or simply do `for _ in range(lineToCheck-1): next(fh)` and then read the wanted line. BTW, enumerate starts counting at zero by default, so your code is bugged